# The specified procedure could not be found (MapVirtualKeyEx) JNA (Java)

Tags: java, windows, api, java-native-interface, jna

I am using JNA and need to use the MapVirtualKeyEx function.

Here is the signature:

```
UINT WINAPI MapVirtualKeyEx(

      __in         UINT uCode,
      __in         UINT uMapType,
      __inout_opt  HKL dwhkl
    );
```

More information on the signature can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646307(v=vs.85).aspx

I tried this:

```
int MapVirtualKeyEx (int uCode, int nMapType, int dwhkl);
```

but it didn't match. I have a feeling it's the `_inout_opt` that's causing the problem.

The error I get is : `The specified procedure could not be found.`

```
        static interface User32 extends Library {
                public static User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("User32", 
                User32.class);

                int MapVirtualKeyEx (int uCode, int nMapType, int dwhkl);
            }


            private static void test(int keyCode)
            {

                int code = User32.INSTANCE.MapVirtualKeyEx(key, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC,
                    134809609); //The number is the keyboard ID, it's temporary.

            }
```

I also have another question: Is there some kind of automated way of converting the API signature so it can be used in JNI/JNA?

Comment: Note: I have read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156055/jna-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found and several others but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MapVirtualKeyEx() deals with characters there is an ANSI and WIDE version of it. Therefore the function is MapVirtualKeyExA()/MapVirtualKeyExW() depending which one you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

For a parameter that is both an input and output parameter, you will need to use one of the JNA reference types. If HKL is indeed an int, use IntByReference. If it's a struct, you'll need to define a corresponding Structure.

As for your other question, try [JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/).

Comment: I've been searching for a long time and couldn't find what HKL means. Thanks for JNAerator. +1